# Uncountable set of sequences of binary digits

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Cantor proved, using diagonalisation, that the set of infinite sequences of binary digits `S` is uncountable (a very simple [proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) can be found at wikipedia).

I do understand his arguments, but I do not understand how that can be: natural numbers can be represented in base 2, covering all of `S`. It seems obvious that there is a bijection between natural numbers and `S`:

```
0 <-> 00000000...
1 <-> 10000000...
2 <-> 01000000...
3 <-> 11000000...
```

and so on. Can anybody explain me please why `S` is still uncountable?

Comment: Which natural would you assign the sequence $01010101010101010101....$? (I mean each odd element is $0$ which each even element is $1$.)

Comment: @user59363, don't worry about it. He said the bijection was *obvious*.

Comment: Well, those are not the strings that Cantor used. A simple click on the link that you've provided yourself shows otherwise.

Comment: This question has been asked so many times. *So many times* already. What's wrong with putting the time you used to write down this post into searching for an answer first?

Comment: OK, now it is clear - thank you. @AsafKaragila I didn't find it in the search-function. Should I delete the question?

Comment: You can't delete the function with an upvoted answer. Next time, try harder. In any case, for future reference, the best way to deal with this on your own is to *apply the proof* of Cantor's theorem to your suggested bijection and see for yourself how it's not really surjective. There's *really* nothing better than that. No matter what people will answer, finding the answer on your own is always better.

Comment: Just to reinforce Asaf Karagila's answer: Whenever you understand (or think you understand) a proof and also see (or think you see) a counterexample, the thing to do is to compare them. Check what the proof says about your specific counterexample. That will show where the error is.

Comment: Application of Cantors proof to your list would return the sequence $11111111111111111111111111111....$ (all ones).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the map you have defined, just the sequences that are $0$ after some point are considered. Thus the sequences changing infinite times, like $0101010101010101...$, are not covered. 
Therefore it is not an onto map and not a bijection.